# Default "null" Select Value Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im developing a ecommerce website where the owner can upload products in three different types: Slider, Top and Catalog, and can also asign them categories like children, men, etc, that are displayed and can be chosen via the Select/Option

```
    <div *ngIf="type==1" class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="description">Categoria</label>   
<div class="styled-select slate">
<select [(ngModel)]="image.category" required>
  <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue]="category.description">{{category.description}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Ok so when choosing to upload a Slider or a Top Product I disable the Select/Option via *ngIf as seen in my code, however I need to assign a default null value in Select/option whenever these are selected, so it can be properly saved in the DB
Any direct help or work around would be appreciated

This is the method that uploads the product

```
uploadImage(){
let formData : FormData = new FormData();

switch(this.type){
  case 1: {
    this.image.type="catalogo";
    break;
  }
  case 2: {
    this.image.type="slider";
    break;
  }
  case 3: {
    this.image.type="destacado";
    break;
  }

}

formData.append('filefield',this.image.file,this.image.file.name);
formData.append('description',this.image.description+'');
formData.append('price',this.image.price+'');
formData.append('type',this.image.type+'');
formData.append('name',this.image.name+'');
formData.append('category',this.image.category+'');

this.service.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/upload",formData).subscribe();
window.location.replace("myra");
```

}

And the object image, which is the product we wish to upload

```
class Image{
name:String;
price:Number;
description:String;
type:String;
file:any;
quantity:Number;
category:String;
```

}